Calculation of $\sum\sum\sum x_ix_jx_k$ using $x_i+x_{n+1-i}=0$
Problem: Suppose that $x_1,...,x_n$ are real numbers such that $x_i = -x_{n-i+1}$ for $1\le i \le n$. Consider the sum $S = \sum\sum\sum x_ix_jx_k$, where the summations are taken over all $i,j,k$: $1\ge i,j,k\ge n$ and $i,j,k$ are all distinct. Then $S$ equals
Context: This problem is a part of the book Test Of Mathematics at 10+2 Level, this book is for the preparation for the admission test for bachelors in an Indian college named Indian Statistical Institute. The question was an MCQ , where I could easily choose the option based on this result (correct option was none of the above) but still I am curious about it.
My attempt: I was initially stuck by the thought that $x_i = -x_{n-i+1}$ means $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=0$, but this is true only in case of $n$ being even which might not be always true. Regardless, I proceeded and here are my steps,
$$
3S=3\sum\sum\sum x_ix_jx_k=\sum\sum x_ix_j(\sum x_k)=\sum\sum x_ix_j(-x_i-x_j)
=-\sum\sum x_i^2x_j+x_j^2x_i
$$
$$
\implies3S=-\sum x_i^2
(\sum x_j)=-\sum x_i^2(-x_i)=-\sum x_i^3=-\sum_{i=1}^{[\frac{n}{2}]}x_i^3+x_{n+1-i}^3\\ =-\sum_{i=1}^{[\frac{n}{2}]}(x_i+x_{n+1-i})(x_{i}^2-x_ix_j+x_j^2)=-\sum_{i=1}^{[\frac{n}{2}]}0.(x_{i}^2-x_ix_j+x_j^2)=0
$$
The solution is taking the assumption that $n$ is even for $n$, but is this also true for n being odd?

If $n$ is odd, the middle-indexed term must be $0$. So I don't see that situation having a different conclusion than the $n$ even case. That middle-indexed term would contribute zero to to the sum and can be omitted, reducing to an even $n$ case.

Denote $M=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, it's easy to notice that $M = 0$ whether $n$ is odd or even. Indeed, for the case $n$ odd, $n = 2u+1$, we have $x_{i}=-x_{2u+2-i}$ for $i=1,..,u$ and $x_{u+1} = -x_{2u+1-(u+1)+1}=-x_{u+1}\implies x_{u+1}=0$, so $M =x_{u+1} + \sum_{i=1}^u (x_i + x_{2u+2-i})=0$).
As a consequence,
$$S = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i\sum_{j=1}^n\left(x_j\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}_{=M}  \right) \right) = \underbrace{M}_{=0}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i\sum_{j=1}^nx_j \right) = 0$$
